# Highlighting Keywords in Search breaking the passing of URL Variables?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

The below code is part of a javascript function that I am using to highlight keywords:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++)
        {
            var a = new RegExp(keywords[i], "igm");
            container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.replace(a, "<span style='background:#FF0;'>" + keywords[i] + "</span>");    
        }
```

It does in fact highlight the words in my search results while allowing the user to click a result. The problem comes when the user clicks a result and is transferred to the page containing more details. Smack in the middle of the URL variables is the 'span' tag.

```
        details.aspx?id=2<span style='background:#FF0> /<span>&name=..
```

This in turn prevents my details page from being properly populated. If I comment out the problem line and use the below code the variables pass smoothly, but the keywords aren't highlighted:

```
             container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.replace(a keywords[i] );
```

My question is how do I remove the span tag from my URL so that my Variables are passed smoothly and the keywords remain highlighted?

Comment: I think you should consider 'changing the visualization' instead of trying to adjust the 'load link' method. Consider adding/removing a class to make the highlight visible without changing the content of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are doing a text search on a string and your code is matching on the attributes inside of tags. You can not do a simple find and replace and you should not use regular expressions to match tags.